# force unique fields while saving embedded documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

**device.rb**

```
class Device
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :devui, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  belongs_to :user
  embeds_many :responses

end
```

The some data, I fetch it from an external server which gives me a json with id field in it. Which when I try to insert in response, the id field gets repeated, and mongo takes the _id to be same as the id that is coming with json array for some data.

**devices_controller.rb**

```
def fetch
        @device_data = "some data"
        @responses = @device.responses.new(@device_data)
        @device.save
        redirect_to @device
      end
```

**responses.rb**

```
class Response
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :dataFrame, type: String
  embedded_in :device
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `mongoid` considers `id` and `_id` as same in case of documents. So, you should skip assigning `id` to the new `Response` object. It is never a good idea to assign the `id` attribute yourself. You can do it like this.

```
@responses = @device.responses.new(@device_data.except(:id))
```

If you really want to store `@device_date[:id]` value, you should add some new field to `Response` model like `device_id` or whatever name and you can store that id in it.

Comment: thank you for the answer.
can i create unique index in embedded documents. like i want to keep the @device_data[:id] unique. how to do that?

Comment: That i am not sure of. But you can add a validation in `Response` class to prevent duplicate entries for *id* i.e. `validates_uniqueness_of :whatever_name_you_chose_for_id_field`